# Does Word Web-Addin support the use of fields?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-js, word-web-addins

It's possible to create a document in word with different fields, like 'address', 'title' etc. But those fields is based of your Contact data you setup in word.

I was wondering if it possible to create a web-addin with your own fields the user can put into their document. I know it can then be merged using Aspose but to generate those fields in the document. 
Is it possible to do that from a web-addin?

Edit:
Did a bit more research and it looks like the fields I'm looking for in Word (Fields, Mergefields etc.) can be made using OOXML, which is possible to add from a Web-Addin though the documentation and how to is not so clear, but it is possible.

Comment: Could you provide any examples of how it should look like?

Comment: What you have in mind is unclear... Are you looking for "input fields" on the document surface to gather user information. (The same idea as a Form, but using the document, itself.) What, if anything, should be done with the user input at a later time? Based on the information given, I'd say research the concept "Content Controls" as those are well-supported in the Word JS API.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add what is known as Fields, MergeFields etc. in word using a Web-Addin.

To do so you need to build what is known as an OOXML document and then pass it to word, which then makes the field inside word based on the information inside the OOXML document.